# a question about Float64MultiArray

Tags: ros, std-msgs

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone

I define my Variable as follow:
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray Atest;
I want to assign a value to specific element. for example i want to change value of fifth element to 5. how i can write it?
Best

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/110831/a-question-about-float64multiarray/) by [sina](https://answers.ros.org/users/616/sina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-12-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Declare the lib:

```
#include <std_msgs/Float64MultiArray.h> //include the lib
```

use it:

```
std_msgs::Float64MultiArray Atest; //declare Atest
Atest.data.resize(5); //resize the array to assign to existent values
Atest.data[4] = 5; //put the desired value
```

---

Originally posted by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) with karma: 357 on 2013-12-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2017-02-11**:
This generates the error `error: request for member 'resize' in 'Atest.std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::data', which is of non-class type 'std_msgs::Float64MultiArray::_data_type* {aka float*}'`

**Comment by [David Galdeano](https://answers.ros.org/users/9481/david-galdeano/) on 2017-02-15**:
It works but maybe not in your case, as explained here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42180378/request-for-member-resize-in-float64multiarray-which-is-of-non-class-type

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Its likes a vector, dont like the array. please according to the using the way to vector, not array.

Atest.data.push_back(5.0);

---

Originally posted by [zhanghao1120](https://answers.ros.org/users/41636/zhanghao1120/) with karma: 11 on 2019-05-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1